# Stability of Extreme Point Solution

Tags: optimization

Suppose I know the solution to the problem:

```
max f(x)
s.t x in conv{a1, a2, ..., an}
```

where `f` is a convex function. It is well known that an optimal solution to this problem lies on one of the extreme points of the convex hull of `{a1, a2, ..., an}`.

My question is the following. Suppose I pertub the convex hull with the following perubation:

```
ak <- ak + c.
```

What would be the demands on `c` and `f` so that the optimal extreme point solution (w.r.t  the order of the `ai`) does not change? In other words, when changing the constraints by a bit I don't want the solution to jump off to a completely different place and would expect it to stay.